# How to change every html tag into space

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, strip-tags

I have stored some html data into database through summernote plugin

in database it look like this

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span id=&quot;job_summary&quot; class=&quot;summary&quot;&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;
&lt;b class=&quot;jobtitle&quot;&gt;&lt;font size=&quot;+1&quot;&gt;Analyst/Junior Analyst- Outbound calling process&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/b&gt;
```

here is how i show it

```
echo text_cut(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($ro)),300);
```

now i want to show this data in plain text on my page, i tried using strip_tags but it makes the looks messy, here is how it looks after strip tags

`knowledgeMust be reliable in terms of attendance and timingExhibit`

it joined the words, so now i want all the html tags to be converted into `&nbsp;` how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
    $spaceString = str_replace('<', ' <', $ro);
    echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($spaceString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try.  If you replace the tags with a space and then replace multiple spaces with one space, it should give you the desired results.

First, use something like this to replace the tags:

```
preg_replace('~&lt;.*?&gt;~i', ' ', $string);
```

[Here is what it will give you](https://regex101.com/r/nZ1iG5/1)

Next, you can look for multiple spaces in a row and consolidate them:

```
preg_replace('~ +~', ' ', $string);
```

That will give you this:

```
Analyst/Junior Analyst- Outbound calling process
```

[Here is a demo of it all together](http://ideone.com/KiFKgp)

You won't really be able to see it, but there is a line above it with a blank space and a blank space before the string as well.  So, depending on what you are wanting the result to look like, you can use a `\s+` instead of `[SPACE]+`

[Here is another demo showing how to do it that way](http://ideone.com/izAunf)